# python remove characters and add crlf to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following file

```
Ichg_UNBUNOA3                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         MSG_BGM380                                         610809                             9  NA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     MSG_DTM13720130422                           102                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Grp1_RFFON test EDI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Grp2_NADBY
```

I need to process it using python 2.7 and add an \r\n after each 640 characters.
this will result in

```
Ichg_UNBUNOA3 14......
MSG_BGM380 610809.....
MSG_DTM13720134022.....
Grp1_RFFON test EDI
Grp2_NADBY.....
```

and then remove all the characters before the '_'

Does somebody has a solution for this?

---

```
    import textwrap
    original= infile.readline()

    line="\r\n".join(textwrap.wrap(original, 640))
    for line in line:
        tofile.write(line)
```

This code results in the following

```
Ichg_UNBUNOA3                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001
MSG_BGM380                                         610809                             9  NA
MSG_DTM13720130422                           102
Grp1_RFFON test EDI
Grp2_NADBY 2090100000015                         9
Grp2_NADIV 2090100000015                         9
```

But now I would like to drop the first characters until the '_'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`textwrap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> strs="Ichg_UNBUNOA3                                   14                2090100000015                      14                1304221445000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         MSG_BGM380                                         610809                             9  NA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     MSG_DTM13720130422                           102                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Grp1_RFFON test EDI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Grp2_NADBY"

#textwrap.fill(strs,640) appends a newline ("\n") after every 640 characters
#use "\r\n".join(textwrap.wrap(strs, 640)) if you want '\r\n' instead of '\n' as newline 

>>> new_strs=textwrap.fill(strs,640)

>>> for line in new_strs.splitlines():
    print " ".join(line.split())
...     
Ichg_UNBUNOA3 14 2090100000015 14 1304221445000001
MSG_BGM380 610809 9 NA
MSG_DTM13720130422 102
Grp1_RFFON test EDI
Grp2_NADBY
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop the first characters until the `_` you can split the string on the `_` and select only the second part.

```
line = line.split('_', 1)[1]
```